# How to parse and extract price-related information from unstructured text data using NLP techniques in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-processing, information-retrieval

I want to extract actual and discount prices from unstructured text; the following are some (simulated) samples of that input text:

> 1. Based on the user rating we recommend to offer the product with a discount of Rs.2500 from an initial price of Rs.10000.This was
>      provided to establish long term relationship with the customers.
> 2. For better relationship we recommend to reduce the product price for the customer to Rs.15000 from Rs.20000. Total discount for the
>      case is Rs.5000
> 3. As provided previously the cost can be reduced 5% from the initial price Rs.22000. This results in an overall discount of Rs.1100

My desired output from the above 3 texts is like this:

```
No ActualPrice  Discount
1 10000         2500
2 20000         5000
3 22000         1100
```

I have used some regular expressions to extract the amount, but as the data is in an unstructured manner regexes don't help much as the patterns are not consistent.
Is there any NLP way to handle these kind of scenarios in Python? I have knowledge of basic NLP techniques (tokenization, ngrams, POS tagging, stopword removal, stemming etc.)

Comment: Err, "Write my e-commerce scraper" is not an acceptable question. You need to show more effort. What code did you try and why does it not do what you want?  Anyway this is just regexes returning numbers which you then do arithmetic on... this isn't NLP. (Unless we are supposed to automatically interpret the true meaning of fields like `Discount` and relate it to `ActualPrice`. But even then that's data-mining, not NLP)

Comment: Ah ok your *input* is the unstructured text and that table is your desired output (one record per input sentence). I rewrote the question to make that clear. Anyway like with any heavily task-specific application, there is no such NLP library, you'll just need to write your own package and functions, and train it on enough sample data to make it robust and useful. It will be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'Based on the user rating we recommend to offer the product with a discount of Rs.2500 from an initial price of Rs.10000.This was provided to establish long term relationship with the customers." I want to extract Rs.10000 and Rs.2500. from next text "For better relationship we recommend to reduce the product price for the customer to Rs.15000 from Rs.20000. Total discount for the case is Rs.5000" I want to extract Rs.20000 and Rs.5000'

import re
results = re.findall('\d+',s)
```

From this text "Based on the user rating we recommend to offer the product with a discount of Rs.2500 from an initial price of Rs.10000.This was provided to establish long term relationship with the customers." I want to extract Rs.10000 and Rs.2500. from next text "For better relationship we recommend to reduce the product price for the customer to Rs.15000 from Rs.20000. Total discount for the case is Rs.5000" I want to extract Rs.20000 and Rs.5000

Comment: Hi. My question is to extract the amount information from the text and not from the table. The table is the final output

Comment: Do you want to extract 10000,25000 then 20000,5000

Comment: From this text "Based on the user rating we recommend to offer the product with a discount of Rs.2500 from an initial price of Rs.10000.This was provided to establish long term relationship with the customers." 
I want to extract Rs.10000 and Rs.2500.

from next text "For better relationship we recommend to reduce the product price for the customer to Rs.15000 from Rs.20000. Total discount for the case is Rs.5000" 
I want to extract Rs.20000 and Rs.5000

Comment: @Haroldo_OK This will fetch all amount values. But how will i know which is the actual amount and which is discount amount?

Comment: @chandru Could any number that follows the word discount be the discount?